# Clear Unordered list button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been staring at the problem for hours.   I am just starting to learn Jquery and I have a small project that requires me to use a button to clear the elements of an unordered list.

First, I most track the mouse posistion and mouse-click of the user.   Each time they click the button, I build an unordered list and record the x,y posistions.  Then, I am supposed to use a button to clear the list.    Everything seems to work fine, but the button when clicked, adds to the list instead of clearing it.

Can anyone help me spot the issue?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Click away</title>
<link href="stylesheets/standard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var count = 0;
$("html").click(function(){
count++; 
$("#display").html("The click count is: " + count);
});
$("html").click(function(e) {
var xPos = e.pageX;
var yPos = e.pageY;
$("#list").append("<li>" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "</li>");
});
//This is the section I can't get to work
$("#clear").click(function () {
$("#list").remove();
}); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1> Click away</h1>
<h2>Start clicking...</h2>  
<h2 id="display"></h2>
<button id="clear">Clear the location list</button> 
<h2>Click locations:</h2>   
<ul id="list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("#list").empty();`

Using `$("#list").children().remove();` will also work but the first one is more efficient.

I think you should also exclude the clear button from your list and put your code inside `.ready()` handler so that the code executes after DOM is ready and your elements are loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var count = 0;
    $("html").click(function () {
        count++;
        $("#display").html("The click count is: " + count);
    });
    $("html").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target !== document.getElementById('clear')) { //exclude the clear button 
            var xPos = e.pageX;
            var yPos = e.pageY;
            $("#list").append("<li>" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "</li>");
        }
    });

    $("#clear").click(function () {
        $("#list").empty(); //empty list
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried implementing this.    When I click the button, the list stops growing and does not add anymore items, but it didn't clear it.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#list").empty();`

it will clear all children of the element.